# Как мне переделать бесконечный цикл while?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, sqlite3, ping

В общем у меня есть цикл перебирающий *`100 ip`* адресов после нажатия кнопки "start", если пакеты проходят, то меняет цвет на зелёный, иначе на красный и выводит данные об этом `ip` из БД.

Но при моём цикле она спокойно может перестать отвечать и перестаёт работать интерфейс.

Пытался сделать в **`2`** потока, но как-то не получилось. 
И как сделать чтобы данные об этом *`ip`* вылазили **`1`** раз ? А лучше просто с открытия программы начинался пинг всех 100 ip  адресов и те какие не прошли - выводились единожды в `PlainText`, а если начали пинговаться, то данные исчезали.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from des import *
import socket, struct

params = False

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

        #Подключение к БД

        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        # Перебор ip адресов и вывод в comboBox

        for row in records:
            self.ui.comboBox.addItem(str(row[0]))

    # Кнопки

    def start(self):
        global params
        params = False

        Thread(target=self.pysh).start()

    def stop(self):
        global params
        params = True

    # Изменение цвета

    def pysh(self):
        style_up = """
            QComboBox{
                color: green
            }
        """

        style_down = """
            QComboBox{
                color: red
            }
        """

        while not params:

            #Пинг
            hostname = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
            response = os.system("ping " + hostname + " -n 2 -w 100")

            #Проверка ответа
            #Если пакеты прошли
            if response == 0:
                self.ui.comboBox.setStyleSheet(style_up)

            #Если не прошли
            else:
                self.ui.comboBox.setStyleSheet(style_down)

                # Подключение к БД

                sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
                cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

                sqlite_select_query = """SELECT Gor, Yi, Location FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(hostname)
                cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
                records = cursor.fetchall()

                # Перебором вставляем данные в PlainText 
                for row in records:
                    self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(row[0]) + "\n" +
                                                          str(row[1]) + "\n" +
                                                          str(row[2]) + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

**des.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(590, 432)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 591, 391))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 120, 191, 22))
        self.comboBox.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 581, 201))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 590, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг портов"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
```

2-ой вариант Main.py, где просто идёт перебор ip, но при нажатии на кнопку "start" - не выводит данные, если не прошел пинг(не остановить пока for не отработает). Пингует все 100 ну прям ооочень долго, des тот-же

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from des import *
import socket, struct

params = False

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def start(self):
        global params
        params = False

        Thread(target=self.pysh).start()

    def stop(self):
        global params
        params = True

    class pysh(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

            sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            style_up = """
                QComboBox{
                    color: green
                }
            """

            style_down = """
                QComboBox{
                    color: red
                }
            """

            while not params:

                #Пинг
                for row in records:
                    response = os.system("ping " + str(row[0]) + " -n 2 -w 100")

                #Проверка ответа
                if response == 0:
                    self.ui.comboBox.setStyleSheet(style_up)

                else:
                    self.ui.comboBox.setStyleSheet(style_down)

                    # Подключение к БД

                    sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
                    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

                    sqlite_select_query = """SELECT Gor, Yi, Location FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(hostname)
                    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
                    records = cursor.fetchall()

                    # Вставляем данные в PlainText 
                    for row in records:
                        self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(row[0]) + "\n" +
                                                              str(row[1]) + "\n" +
                                                              str(row[2]) + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

БД с некими данными
[image: БД]

Попытавшись модифицировать свой код по вашему примеру, получилось следующее, в котором есть нужный вам `read_table`, `onUpdate` ещё не менял т.к. не могу ещё справиться с ошибкой которая выдаётся при запуске -

```
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from des import *
import socket, struct

#Подключение к БД
# def read_hosts():
#   sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
#   cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

#   sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
#   cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
#   records = cursor.fetchall()
#   for row in records:
#       return row[0]

class set_ping(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        update = pyqtSignal(str, int)
        exception = pyqtSignal(str)

    def pings(self):
        hosts = read_hosts()
        table = read_table()
        while True:
            for column in range(table.columnCount()):
                for row in range(table.rowCount()):
                    text = str(table.item(row, column).text())
                    
                    response = os.system("ping " + text + " -n 2 -w 100")

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.read_table()
        self.startWorker()

        # self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        # self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def read_table(self):

        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)

        self.table_index = 0
        self.row_count = 1

        #Подключение к БД

        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()     

        # Перебор ip адресов

        for row in records:
            self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))

            self.table_index += 1
            self.row_count += 1

        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        style_def = """QTableWidget::item {background-color: white;
                     border-style: outset;
                     border-width: 3px; border-radius: 7px; border-color: DimGray;
                     }"""

        self.setStyleSheet(style_def)

    def startWorker(self):
        self.thread = QThread() 
        self.obj = set_ping() 
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.update.connect(self.onUpdate)
        self.obj.exception.connect(self.onException)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.pings)
        self.thread.start()

    def onException(self, msg):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "В Workerе было брошено исключение: ", msg)

    def onUpdate(self, host, value):
        table = self.findChild(QLabel, host)
        table.setText("{}".format(value))
        if value:
            style_1 = """QTableWidget::item {background-color: white;
                                 border-style: outset;
                                 border-width: 3px; border-radius: 7px; border-color: red;
                                 }"""
        else:
            style_2 = """QTableWidget::item {background-color: white;
                                 border-style: outset;
                                 border-width: 3px; border-radius: 7px; border-color: green;
                                 }"""

            sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT Gor, Yi, Location FROM ips WHERE ip = '{}'""".format(hostname)
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            # Вставляем данные в PlainText 
            for row in records:
                self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(str(row[0]) + "\n" +
                                                      str(row[1]) + "\n" +
                                                      str(row[2]) + "\n")
                        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**des.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(589, 431)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 591, 391))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 581, 151))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 10, 131, 191))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 110, 151, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 589, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action123 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123.setObjectName("action123")
        self.action123_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action123_2.setObjectName("action123_2")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action123_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Мониторинг"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ip"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Пинг портов"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.action123.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
        self.action123_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "123"))
```

Создание и заполнение данными БД -

```
import sqlite3

# Добавление данных в таблицы

try:
    connect = sqlite3.connect("News.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print("База данных подключена к SQLite")
    
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip(
                      ip INTEGER);""")

    connect.commit()

    records = [[f"192.168.{i}.9"] for i in range(1, 101)]
    cursor.executemany("insert into ip values(?)", records)
    connect.commit()

    print("Запись успешно добавлена")
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)

finally:
    if connect:
        connect.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Comment: @S. Nick Зачем было менять спустя 6 месяцев ? :DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt    import *


def read_hosts():
    file = open("hosts.ini", "r") 
    return file.readlines() 


class Worker(QObject):
    update    = pyqtSignal(str, int)
    exception = pyqtSignal(str)

    def check_ping(self):
        hosts = read_hosts()
        fl = True
        while fl:
            for host in hosts:
                params = "-n 2 -w 100"
                response = os.system("ping  {} {}".format(host, params))
                print("дальше")
                self.update.emit(host, response)
                
            fl = False


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        hosts = read_hosts()
        for host in hosts:
            label = QLabel(host)
            label.setObjectName(host)
            label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: #8ad7c1;}")
            self.layout.addWidget(label)
        self.startWorker()

    def startWorker(self):
        self.thread = QThread() 
        self.obj    = Worker()  
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.update.connect(self.onUpdate)
        self.obj.exception.connect(self.onException)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.check_ping)
        self.thread.start()

    def onException(self, msg):
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "В Workerе было брошено исключение: ", msg)

    def onUpdate(self, host, value):
        label = self.findChild(QLabel, host)
        label.setText("{}".format(value))
        if value:
            label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: #fa7f72;}")
        else:
            label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: #54e346;}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(200, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**hosts.ini**

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.1.9
192.168.2.9
192.168.0.30
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересный способ, но когда я начинаю вытаскивать ip из бд - на этапе read_hosts он целый, а на этапе Worker -при пинге он разбивается на отдельные элементы, как поправить ?

Comment: И пингует он по 4 пакета, а не как было задано по 2

Comment: Ну и как ускорить процесс пинга ? Это прям жуть как медленно

Comment: При пинге того ip до которого пакеты не дошли, он пишет про какой-то левый узел 192.168.0.20 и всё равно делает зелёным :D

Comment: @OverNiko это один из возможных вариантов создания дополнительных потоков в `PyQt`. В основном потоке не должно быть никаких циклов `while` - это замораживает интерфейс. Глобальные переменные - это ЗЛО. Другие вопросы, которые вы начинаете уточнять, никак не касаются `PyQt`, поэтому, я так думаю, вам надо задать другой вопрос, который касается этих проблем.

Comment: Это вопросы конкретно по вашему коду

Comment: По ускорению да - согласен, другой вопрос

Comment: @OverNiko мой ответ не помог решить вашу проблему?

Comment: Решить - нет, но был полезен

Comment: На вашем примере я понял, что нужно в отдельные класс делать, но как это делать - загадка

Comment: Можете дополнить ваш код вызовом ip из БД а не из файла ?

Comment: @OverNiko могу попробовать, если вы предоставите скрипт, который создает нужную таблицу и ее заполнение данными.

Comment: Добавил то что на данный момент сделано

Comment: И сам скрипт создания и заполнения БД

Comment: Я сделал, как в ваш код добавить скролл бар ?

Answer (score 0):

Быстрый метод исправить

fetchall замени на for row in con.execute()... Во все циклы вставь
QApplication.processEvents()

Comment: sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip FROM ips"""
    cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
    records = for row in con.execute() ?

Comment: Не надо забирать все результаты за раз. По одному

Comment: А можно пример ?